# Facebook graph API, only request posts with Images

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have searched high and low but I cannot find any clear instructions how to only request posts that have the 'full_picture' (or at a push any image that can be pulled) parameter through the Facebook Graph API v.2.5 . I thought that maybe the 'with' modifier would do the trick but no dice so far. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

this is the basic query I am trying in the graph explorer :

browjamacademy?fields=posts.with(full_picture).limit(1){full_picture}

cheers

Comment: there is no filter, you will have to do that on your own after getting all entries

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was starting to wonder that myself but thought it was implausible. So you just have to pull in X amount and hope that one has an image in it? It is likely one will I realise, but it seems unsatisfactory that I would have to leave it to chance.